# Python projects - inherit common dependencies from a "parent" dependency file

Tags: python, maven, dependencies, dependency-management, pypi

I have many python applications (separate git repos) that share some common dependencies.  I want to have some sort of parent dependency file where each of the dependencies are defined and in each python app I can simply refer to this parent file and these dependencies are used.

Coming from a Java/Maven background I have done this before with a parent pom (in a separate git repo and versioned) that defines all of the dependencies in dependencyManagement and then each application depends on this parent, which then ensures that all of the dependencies and versions are inherited to each application.

Is there a similar way of doing this in the Python eco-system?

Edit: Also is there a way to override a dependency to use a specific version in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the following is `base.txt` containing common pip dependencies:

```
Pillow>=5.0
pynput>=1.4
```

And then `linux.txt` contains the following:

```
-r base.txt
PyGObject>=3.32
python-xlib>=0.17
```

To install both, you just call:

```
pip install -r linux.txt
```

Comment: Is `base.txt` in the root of the project here?  I would like `base.txt` to be versioned and in git as a tag / or in an artifact repo.  And then referenced in `linux.txt` with the version. is this possible?

Comment: I guess you could rename base.txt to base-*tag*.txt, but that's not an elegant solution. You may set the exact path with -e, but not sure for requirements file. Check the [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files).

Comment: Yeah i've checked the docs and it seems a constraints file could work, but the docs are always referring to a local file, (like in your example), but i need to refer to a remote file such as a git url or artifactory dependency